# Accessing object (using reference or pointer) from a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, object, pointers, reference

I have a C++ process that initialize a class that store in a `std::map` some data, and then  another class -- that will be executed in a thread -- to which I pass a pointer (I tried also a reference) of the first class because it will need to access the content of the `std::map` (using a getter).

What is happening is that the data from the `std::map` of the first class is never updated when I update it from the main thread.

My question is my problem caused I'm using a thread so that the object is copied and then doesn't received updates ?
And how to solve this ?

Thank you

Comment: You cannot "initialize a class". You can only initialize *objects*.

Comment: You really need to post some code. We don't know if you are passing by copy or by reference, how you are creating your thread, etc

Comment: And you cannot execute a class either (even though at times I wish I could execute some library designers ^_^).

Answer (score 2):

No, `std::map` is an ordinary container and has nothing to do with threads.  Most likely you have a synchronization issue between your threads, such as a race condition where one thread is looking at the map before or at the same time as another thread is updating the map.  Strange things can happen in these cases because `std::map` may change a lot of internal pointers in re-balancing the tree when something is added, changed, or removed.  Another thread looking at the map at the same time could get "confused".

Try using a semaphore or mutex when accessing the map from either thread, and see if that resolves your issue.

Comment: Please don't use semaphores!  Use std::mutex.  There is a reason that the C++11 committee didn't include a std::semaphore. Semaphores are "too flexible" and thus harder to reason about correctness (both for humans _and for tools_.)

Answer (score 0):

First thank you all for your comments (even comments that doesn't helped).

I finally found the issue I had.
I am using Boost signals to update the class containing the `std::map` and was passing my class instantiation without the `&` so was working on a copy.